# jssor Nested Sliders with Arrow Navigations - Loop through all nested sliders + autoplay duration bug

Tags: jssor

... long topic :)

I'm using the jssor nested slider and added navigation_arrows - and the entire thing is auto-playing (with 8 secs between each slide)

the first problem I have is - 
the arrow-navigations doesn't reset the timeout on the sliders,
so say 7 secs passed and I click one of the arrow-keys then I will get the next image for 1 second and then it'll move to the next one (due to the 8 secs autoloop duration...)

the 2nd problem - I'm trying to make it so the arrow key will move to the next nested slider once it finishes its current one.

I've used the code posted here in another topic -

```
var childSlider = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, nestedSliderOptions);
            childSlider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, OnChildSliderStateChange);
            nestedSliders.push(childSlider);
            function OnChildSliderStateChange(slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd) {
                var childSlider = nestedSliders[jssor_slider1.$CurrentIndex()];
                if (progress == progressEnd && slideIndex == childSlider.$SlidesCount() - 1) {
                    //last slide (of current chlid sldier) plays over, pause the child slider, and move the main slider next
                    childSlider.$Pause();
                    childSlider.$GoTo(0);
                    jssor_slider1.$Next();
                }
            }
```

but this one only works for the autoplay, and not the navigation arrows :(

help please? :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is the arrow navigator for main slider? Or for child slider?

Comment: I've put them on the child slider in order for them to show up on all nested sliders

Comment: Every child slider need an arrow navigator then. But they can share the same css.

Comment: they all have arrow navigations :)
its the 2 problems in the post that I have :\

Comment: Please leave me an url of your work or send me via email (jssor@live.com). Also, please describe the 2 problems more in detail.

Comment: Interested in this exact answer as well. Did you ever come up with a solution or able to point in the correct direction?